# Using LineFillSymbol in polygon layer from ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, symbology

I'm creating a symbol hatch:

```
var lineFill = new LineFillSymbolClass
{
    Angle = 45,
    Offset = 0,
    Separation = 0.1,
    Outline = new SimpleLineSymbolClass { Style = esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSSolid, Color = Color.FromArgb(215, 15, 245).ToRgbColorClass(), Width = 0.5 },
    LineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass { Style = esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSSolid, Color = Color.FromArgb(215, 152, 245).ToRgbColorClass(), Width = 0.5 }
};
((IGeoFeatureLayer)featureLayer).Renderer = new SimpleRendererClass { Symbol = lineFill };
```

Instead of hatch, makes the background simple fill.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to be using `LineFillSymbol` you are using `SimpleLineSymbol`.

Comment: The question is solved!

Comment: The property LineSymbol, need to use - new SimpleLineSymbolClass { Style = esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSSolid, Color = Color.FromArgb(215, 152, 245).ToRgbColorClass(), Width = 0.5 }.

And assign the property Separation = 1 ... N